# HTML5 audio getting stuck after few seconds on Safari, iOS

Tags: ios, safari, html5-audio

Have problem with playing mp4 audio file on Safari and iOS.
  When click `play()` audio starts payback and getting stuck after few seconds, when click again audio continues playing and getting stuck again.
In console have

> "Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load".

The study of this error did not yield any results.

Comment: Do you use VLC or Quicktime plugins with Safari?

Comment: Hi, K3N, no, I don`t